# How to make an image rotate around itself and around a circle?

Tags: xcode5

I have an image of a curved rectangle which is part of a circle so what I want is for the rectangle to rotate in a circular way as if it's the only visible part of the circle while rotating around itself to get the required effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should use a CGAffineTransform.

The key is setting up the center point of the "circle".  You need to know where, relative to the x,y corner of your image is the center.

Then you just need to set your layer's anchor point like this:

```
self.layer.anchorPoint(x, y);
```

Then when you set the transform, just give it the angle (ranging from 0 to 2pi) that you want

```
self.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotations(angleInRadians);
```

You can even have this be part of a view animation.  Just set the starting rotation, then inside your animation block, set the transform to the new value.